# how to save output of a python script in text file in different manner

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, sys

```
import cv2
import math
import sys
sys.stdout = open("output.txt","w")`
img = cv2.imread("#Image_path",1)
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("output",img_gray)
R = 0
C = 0
while R<=441 and C<332:

    print(img_gray[R,C])
    R += 1
    if R == 332:

        print("/n")
        C += 1
        R = 0
sys.stdout.close()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code I want to save the output of this code in matrix form but in my code, it saves all the output in a single column and wants in row and column format

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(img_gray[R,C],)
```

Note the additional comma.

Good luck

Andreas

Comment: If this did indeed solve your problem, then please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you and good luck.